# OnTriggerExit lasting longer than normal?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have an empty object that holds the script below. What I'm achieving is IF an enemy goes within this trigger box the player cannot do anything (they are stunned). It is until they press "W" that the enemy will be `setActive() false`.My issue is when I press "W" the character stays stunned for a long period of time even if the enemy is no longer active on the scene. I want that the minute players press "W" the stun is completely gone and not long lasting. I also notice that if I mash the "W" key it takes a while for confirmation that `OnTriggerExit` is then noticed.

```c#
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class NoCasting : MonoBehaviour 
{

    [SerializeField]
    private Image customImage;

    //public Animator anim;

    public Casting stop;
    public AudioSource source;
    public AudioSource negative;
    public AudioSource helps;
    public AudioSource positive;
    public ParticleSystem stun;


    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () 
    {
        //anim = GetComponent<Animator> ();
        source = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }


    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.tag == "Enemy")
        {
            customImage.enabled = true;

            Debug.Log ("is working trigger");
            stop.GetComponent<Casting> ().enabled = false;
            source.Play ();
            negative.Play ();
            stun.Play ();
            //anim.Play ("DaniAttack");
        }

    }

    private void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown ("w"))
        {
            Debug.Log ("is ended trigger");
            stun.Stop ();
            negative.Stop ();
            stop.GetComponent<Casting> ().enabled = !stop.enabled;
            customImage.enabled = false;
            helps.Play ();
            positive.Play ();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you think my setActive has something to do with this or is it how big the trigger box is? because I have 3 or more enemies that spawn around the same time. They all attract to the player and since they come from such a far location the box is pretty spread out far.

Comment: Oh just deleted my comment (moved it to the answer). Where do you use setActive? If it is false then the enemy won't trigger anything as it is inactive

Comment: The problem is that both `OnTriggerExit` and `GetKeyDown` are only true for *a single frame.* If the user doesn't depress the W key at the exact, same, 1/60th interval that something leaves the trigger zone, then nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

You are checking the input in the `OnTriggerExit` which will only work when the enemy has gone out from the trigger area. (i.e. if he is still near the play the `"W"` press won't be even checked).

You can try the following solution:

Add a boolean member indicating that the player is stunned (set it to `true` in `OnTriggerEnter` inside the if statement and set it to false on `OnTriggerExit`)

Move the "W" press key check block to the `Update()` method.

Comment: I'm referring to a script that is called Casting which is enabling and disabling already. Is it safe enough to use that alone as a boolean or create a whole new one your suggesting?

Answer (score 0):

Since you will have to detect the input in `Update` anyways, I don't really see why you would still need `OnTriggerExit` in this case (since you also want it to be instant).

Just do something like this:

```c#
private bool isStunned = false;     // Add this so code isn't run when not stunned

private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    if(isStunned == false && other.gameObject.tag == "Enemy")
    {
        Stun();
    }
}

private void Update()
{
    if(isStunned == true && Input.GetKeyDown("w"))
    {
        Unstun();
    }
}

public void Stun()
{
    isStunned = true;

    // Do the stuff for stunning
}

public void Unstun()
{
    // Do the stuff that is needed for unstunning

    isStunned = false;
}
```

Also, on another note: Since your `stop` member is of type `Casting`, you don't need to write `stop.GetComponent<Casting>().enabled`, `stop.enabled` is enough. (I guess, it may have been `GameObject stop` at some point.)